# Getting the content stored with file_get_contents

Tags: php

Alright so everything is being saved properly but how can I get the url of the file I am saving?

```
$songs = file_get_contents('https://example.com/tracks/'.$id.'/');
file_put_contents('./tmp/' . stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($songTitle)) . '.mp3', $songs);
```

Without manually having to get every url, please note I am a new developer still learning.. but is there not something I can just echo into an `<a href=""></a>` ??

Edit: `' . stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($songTitle)) . '` this is just the name of the file that we're downloading, nothing important about that string.

Comment: wait... you need filepath or public URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your setup, but if your script is in an externally accessible location and you trust `$_SERVER` client-defined fields, you can use `__FILE__` and `$_SERVER` to accomplish what you want.

The code below assumes:

- Your server is not on HTTPS;
- Files in the subdirectory `tmp` can be accessed externally;
- You can write to the subdirectory `tmp`.
- `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` can be "trusted".

Try this:

```
// This is the only thing you need to set to your taste.
$dest_rel_path = 'tmp/' . stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($songTitle)) . '.mp3';

// This is the final file path in your filesystem.
// `dirname(__FILE__)` can be replaced with __DIR__ in PHP >= 5.3.0
// and the str_replace() part makes the code portable to Windows.
$filesystem_path = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $dest_rel_path);

$songs = file_get_contents('https://example.com/tracks/'.$id.'/');
file_put_contents($filesystem_path, $songs);

// This takes the URL that the user requested and replaces the
// part after the last '/' with our new .mp3 location.
$req_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url_path = substr($req_uri, 0, 1 + strrpos($req_uri, '/')) . $dest_rel_path;
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $url_path;
echo "<a href=\"$url\">This is my link to $songTitle!</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least not directly, since it does not work that way: the filesystem does not necessarily translate to an URL.

For instance, in your case, you're saving the file into the tmp directory. I doubt that directory is accessible in any way to the outside world, ie, that it has a public URL than you can access in your browser.

Comment: example.com/something/bla.mp3 is what I am looking for, but when I do this it seems not to work with the code you displayed above is there anyway I can do this including the entire url from start to finish instead of just from /tmp/ forward?

Comment: He's *not* saving it to the temp dir.